# Append two data sources in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Any idea how I can append popular data on unpopular data

```
private void Bind()
{       
    var unpopular = ChannelHelper.GetUnpopular();
    var popular = ChannelHelper.GetPopular();
    Grid.DataSource = popular + unpopular; 
    Grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: can you specify what type of collections are popular and unpopular? are they ADO.net objects or lists ?

Answer (score 3):

Merge these two data source in a single data source and bind the GridView to the single data source.

If these data source are DataTable or DataSet, you can use [DataTable.Merge](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge.aspx) Method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ADO.net objects i.e  for example Data Tables , Use the follwing syntax to merge the datas

```
foreach( datarow dr in dtunpopular.rows.count)
{
  dtPopular.Import(dr);
}
```

So, all the Unpopular records are merged into Poplar data table.

If, you are lists, then you can similarly iterate through the list and each item to a new list

Answer (score 0):

if both results returning the same object, then you can merge it

```
1- if the datatype was datatable then use Sachin idea
2- if list then use popular.Concat(Unpopular).ToList();
```

hope it will help you
regards

Comment: data.InsertRange(0,popularChannel);

Answer (score 0):

I got solution by below code...

```
data.InsertRange(0,popularChannel);
```

And this also works...

```
grdViewOrders.DataSource = populerChannel.Cast<object>().Union(data.Cast<object>());
```

Thanks all... :)